# Filter rows of a huge csv file based on values in 2 columns

Tags: bash, shell-script, csv

I have a .csv files as shown below:

```
RepDate;FOO1;ProcessId;ClusterName;ProcessType
19700101;-1;Job_1000969943637142044;PROD;auswertung.mpeTestPlayer.xml
20181231;root;Job_107953405843118835;PROD;mpeEditTablesImport.xml
```

Now we want to filter rows when the `ProcessType` is `mpeEditTablesImport.xml` and `ClusterName` is `PROD`.

I have tried the following code, but it is giving empty output:

```
awk -F "," '{ if(($ProcessType == "mpeEditTablesImport.xml") && ($ClusterName ==  "PROD")) { print } }' OutputFile.csv > OutputFile_Filtered.csv | tail
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is useful.

Comment: What are `$ProcessType` and `$ClusterName`? Are you expecting those to match columns with that name?

Comment: @tredon those are my column names.

Comment: That's not how `awk` works, I'm afraid. See answer.

Comment: If you want to refer to columns by name rather than number, you'll need to use tools that have good support for CSV built in, like [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit), or GNU [datamash](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/); or programming languages with CSV-parsing libraries like perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) or python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).  In theory, you could write a decent CSV parser in awk. In practice, it's easier and better to use existing tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk works by splitting the line into fields which are then referred to by the field *number* and not by the text in the field. So you don't use `$field1` for the first field, you use `$1` and then `$2` for the second and so on. What you want is:

```
$ awk -F';' '$5=="mpeEditTablesImport.xml" && $4=="PROD"'  file
20181231;root;Job_107953405843118835;PROD;mpeEditTablesImport.xml
```

In this case, you could also simply use `grep`:

```
$ grep ';PROD;mpeEditTablesImport.xml$' file
20181231;root;Job_107953405843118835;PROD;mpeEditTablesImport.xml
```

Comment: It worked, thanks for the explanation.